# Flash/PHP File Upload Speed Issues

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3, upload

I am trying to write a simple, in-house file delivery application for uploading files for easy download on our client's end. I am using Flash with a very basic PHP script receiving the file. So far, this does work.

The problem statement is: using FTP, a 100 MB file will upload in 2-3 minutes. Using my simple Flash uploader and uploading to the same destination, it takes 3-5x longer. Is there any way I can adjust my PHP/Apache settings to improve upload time?

FLA: http://shorttext.com/ku018nj56s

PHP: http://shorttext.com/5thixgjtr

Comment: 100 MB in 2-3 minutes? Man you have a fast connection :)

Comment: not sure if it makes a difference, but you could be missing a couple params in your actionscript...
request.contentType = "multipart/form-data";
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

Comment: @Amaerghosh heelllll yeah i do! Comcast Business Class...shitty customer service, great up/down speeds.

Comment: @Jascha I get the same results with or without those parameters.

Comment: What is the speed of uploading when using a html form? I myself do find FTP is the fastest for uploading. Maybe that's the protocol different.

Comment: By uploading it via flash/http I believe you get a 33% size increase because it gets base 64 encoded, that doesn't account for 3-5x more though.

Comment: @Kristoffer: depend the way flash handle it, but there is no need for Base64 so I don't things it get actually encoded, I am more thinking that flash limit itself the resource it is using. let's say if you build bad flash you can kill the performance of the user machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't imagine that much of an overhead with a Flash upload component.
Can you, as Xeoncross has already recommended, use a different one just to make sure it's nothing program specific? [SWFUpload](http://www.swfupload.org/)'s standard example should be quite easy to set up.

Then, is there any post-processing happening on the server and that might prolong the request? What happens if you let the receiving script die() right away, is the time difference still that much?

How (with what hostname/IP) are you addressing the FTP server, and how does the browser address the script that parses the upload?

I don't think there is anything you can do on the PHP end of things, because the PHP script only comes into play when the file has been fully uploaded. The only thing there could be a web server misconfiguration - Apache or whatever you're running - but this is a very remote possibility.

Comment: Unfortunately, I wasn't thinking when I set the bounty. I am currently on vacation and haven't been able to test anything, but I think this answer brought me the most insight. I am going to investigate all of these options and will post when/if I find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I would recomend that you try a pre-built flash unloader like the beautiful [FancyUpload](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/) powered by the mootools Javascript framework. For one, it has been around and open source for much longer so it will be optimized. Second, if it is still slower than FTP (which it will be) then you will know that the fact of the matter is, the overhead of FLASH + Apache + PHP just can't beat the speed of a direct FTP connection.

There are many other uploaders also - from standalone to [jQuery](http://www.uploadify.com/)!

Answer (score 0):

can you use an XMLHTTPRequest and upload via HTTP?